# Passing special character [char(11), char(7)] in stored procedure as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, special-characters

I want to search in table for all records with a special characters - char(11), char(7) etc.

I have found one stored procedure which helps me to find it. But it is not accepting the input parameters as follows:

```
EXEC sp_FindStringInTable '%'+char(7)+'%', 'CPOA-TALENTLink-Test-Leeds', 'TALENT_Contact_ChangeLog'
```

**Error**:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_FindStringInTable 
     @stringToFind NVARCHAR(100), 
     @schema SYSNAME, 
     @table SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WHERE ' 

    SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @stringToFind + ''' OR '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
      AND TABLE_NAME = @table 
      AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')

    SET @sqlCommand = LEFT(@sqlCommand, LEN(@sqlCommand) - 3)

    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
   PRINT @sqlCommand
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
   PRINT 'There was an error. Check to make sure object exists.'
   PRINT error_message()
END CATCH
```

As mentioned in error, I'm unable to search through table for special characters.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calls to procedures expressions other than literals or variables don't work.

Assign the concatenation to a variable and pass that variable to the procedure.

```
DECLARE @p varchar(max) = '%' + char(7) + '%';

EXEC sp_FindStringInTable @p, 'CPOA-TALENTLink-Test-Leeds', 'TALENT_Contact_ChangeLog';
```

Comment: This does not address the huge injection vulnerability in your SQL though, @PratikSoni .You *really* need to fix that.

Comment: For example someone could pass something like `EXEC sp_FindStringInTable '', 'YourTable]; CREATE LOGIN NewSA WITH PASSWORD = ''abc123'', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;/*','*/ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewSA;--';` and you may well have a brand new SA on your Server.

Answer (score 0):

Literal string concatenation like `'[' + @schema + ']'` and `' LIKE ''' + @stringToFind + ''''` isn't safe. **Far from it**. I suspect that parametrising your query is going to fix this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_FindStringInTable @stringToFind NVARCHAR(100), @schema sysname, @table sysname 
AS

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(max);
        SET @sqlCommand = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) + --Formatting yoru dynamic SQL is a very good idea
                          N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@table) + NCHAR(10) +
                          N'WHERE' +
                          STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'  AND ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N'LIKE @String'
                                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
                                   AND TABLE_NAME = @table 
                                   AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')
                                 FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,6,N'')
        PRINT @sqlCommand; --your best friend
        EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'String nvarchar(100)', @String = @stringToFind;

        END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
       PRINT 'There was an error. Check to make sure object exists.'
       PRINT error_message()
    END CATCH
```

Note that I **have not** tested the above. Your best friend is there to help you debug.